# Google Spreadsheet to CSV in Google Drive

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets, drive

While uploading CSV file to Google drive, it automatically converting to Google Sheets. How to save it as CSV file in drive? or can I read google sheet through pandas data frame ?

Develop environment: Google Colab

**Code Snippet**:

**Input**

```
data = pd.read_csv("ner_dataset.desktop (3dec943a)", 
encoding="latin1").fillna(method="ffill")

data.tail(10)
```

**Output**

```
    [Desktop Entry]
0   Type=Link
1   Name=ner_dataset
2   URL=https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w0...
```

Comment: This might help you: gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest

Answer (score 2):

**WORKING CODE**

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()

import gspread
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

gc = gspread.authorize(GoogleCredentials.get_application_default())

worksheet = gc.open('Your spreadsheet name').sheet1

# get_all_values gives a list of rows.
rows = worksheet.get_all_values()
print(rows)

# Convert to a DataFrame and render.
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#Mount the Drive
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('drive')

#Authenticate you need to do with your credentials, fill yourself
gauth = GoogleAuth()

#Create CSV and Copy
df.to_csv('data.csv')
!cp data.csv drive/'your drive'
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Following code working for me.

`
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()

import gspread
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

gc = gspread.authorize(GoogleCredentials.get_application_default())

worksheet = gc.open('Your spreadsheet name').sheet1

# get_all_values gives a list of rows.
rows = worksheet.get_all_values()
print(rows)

# Convert to a DataFrame and render.
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows)
`

Comment: @Phani, You can answer your own question, People who will be looking for the code might help . You can paste down. Thanks for using stack over flow